# adding complex objet to Arralist of object problem

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

i try to create a list of this object for java web project:

```
package com.example.data;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class StudentGroup {

private String fullName;
private HashMap<Lesson, Integer> lessonsNumber;


public StudentGroup() {
    lessonsNumber = new HashMap<>();
}

public StudentGroup(String fullName, HashMap<Lesson, Integer> lessonsNumber) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.lessonsNumber = lessonsNumber;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public HashMap<Lesson, Integer> getLessonsNumber() {
    return lessonsNumber;
}

public void setLessonsNumber(HashMap<Lesson, Integer> lessonsNumber) {
    this.lessonsNumber = lessonsNumber;
}

public void addLesson(Lesson lesson, int number){
    this.lessonsNumber.put(lesson, number);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StudentGroup{" +
            "fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
            ", lessonsNumber=" + lessonsNumber.toString() +
            '}';
}
```

}

inside jsp page

here is my jsp code:

```
    List<StudentGroup> studentGroupList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nostudentgroup")); i++) {
    StudentGroup tempstd = new StudentGroup();
    tempstd.setFullName(request.getParameter("studentgroup" + i));

    HashMap<Lesson, Integer> t = new HashMap<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nosubject" + i)); j++) {
        out.println(request.getParameter("stgrpsubject" + i + "-" + j));
        for (int k = 0; k < lessons.size(); k++) {
            if(lessons.get(k).getName().equals(request.getParameter("stgrpsubject" + i + "-" + j))){

                t.put(lessons.get(k), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subjecttime" + i + "-" + j)));
                sum += Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subjecttime" + i + "-" + j));
            }
        }
    }


    tempstd.setLessonsNumber(t);
    out.println("<br>"+ tempstd.toString() +"<br>");
    studentGroupList.add(tempstd);
}
```

the out.println works fine and print tempstd object properly.
but the list(studentGroup) contain empty hashmap for all indexes.
is there any problem with .add method?

thank for any suggestion.

Comment: Help me understand this better. Which list in your code is showing as empty here?

Comment: the hashamp inside student object is empty after adding student object to list @shivam puri

Comment: Where did we change the value of lessons ?

Comment: So are you saying that ```tempstd.setLessonsNumber(t)``` this code sets the map but after ```studentGroupList.add(tempstd)``` you are not able to get the list? Can you edit the question with details about how you are trying to get the map after the ```add``` method.